# How to get rid of title on mouse hover on font awesome svg icon (using svg sprites)

Tags: html, svg, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

**Edit**: this questions is irrelevant in case you're using *Font Awesome* v. >= 5.8.0 because its maintainers (after a long discussion:)), agreed that the "title" should be removed from the svg files and it's done in v. 5.8.0 : https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/14595

Now, back to the original question:

I just tried the Font Awesome (5) in its 'svg sprites' version, following the official, pretty simple tutorial: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/svg-sprites

Everything's working as expected, except I can see a title popping up when I hover on the image (which is bad). I mean the one we see when we have e.g. `<div title = "blah"></div>`.

So, in compliance with the docs (I guess), I have copied the 'sprites/regular.svg' file to my server and:

```
<svg class = 'fa-svg-icon' title = 'my failed attempt to overwrite the title'>
    <use xlink:href="icons/font-awesome/sprites/solid.svg#user"></use>
</svg>
```

The '.fa-svg-icon' class, for the sake of completeness:

```
.fa-svg-icon{
    width:1em;
    height:1em;
}
```

What I see, when hoovering the image, is a title "User" showing up. That's is because this is what is declared in the svg file, in "our" fragment:

```
<symbol id="user" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
    <title id="user-title">User</title>
    <path d="M224 256c70.7 0 ......"></path>
</symbol>
```

I tried adding `title = 'something'` to both the svg element, and the `<use>` one, but nothing works o.O

This happens on both FX and Chrome.

**Edit 1**: I made a test page: https://kpion.github.io/stuff/font-awesome-issue/

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious here, because apparently I'm the only one in this world having this problem  Or google is broken. One or the other :)

**Edit 2**: 
To answer a question from comments, here is what my dev tools -> elements in chrome shows (after 'importing' the svg symbol):

```
<svg class="fa-svg-icon" title="my -not-working-title for user">
    <use xlink:href="icons/font-awesome/sprites/solid.svg#user" title="blah - doesn't work either"></use>
    #shadow-root (closed)
    <svg id="user" viewBox="0 0 448 512" width="100%" height="100%">
        <title id="user-title">User</title>
        <path d="M224 256c70.7 0 128-57.3 128-..."></path>
    </svg>  
</svg>
```

And no, it does not change when hovering, please bear in mind there is no js involved, either mine or from font awesome.

Comment: In your page, if you look at the actual html, what is the element that has the attribute "title" on it and is the attribute always there or only when you hover over it?

Comment: @NTR - thanks for your interest, I updated the question accordingly. Maybe I'll emphasize it - there is no js involved, no magic, nothing on the css on :hover or anything. No nothing :)

Comment: Tried to reproduce the issue without fontawesome and wasn't able to. Seems like the problem might be with that. I'm not the right person to investigate further unfortunatly. Good luck !

Comment: Unless you need to click the font please try adding `pointer-events:none` in CSS

Comment: @enxaneta Thanks for your interest as well, I can confirm it "works", but no, it's not a solution in my case. I want to use font awesome + svg in my projects, including those where you click on the icons and those where you don't. So I'm now looking for a general solution not a specific project case one:)

Comment: remove the title elements if you don't want them.

Comment: @RobertLongson - Thanks. But - it isn't mine, it's an icon library, which might bring more icons in the future, when updated. It's a third party library, I shouldn't mess with it, and I shouldn't be forced to do it... I mean - it isn't a random package from a middle of nowhere, but one of the most popular icon packages here on this planet o.O I am (or was) pretty sure there must be a more... normal / typical way. All of this is just.... weird.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to recreate your code environment in a fiddle to try it myself, but you may try the following CSS code, to get the pointer-events only when the icon has a link:

```
.fa-svg-icon{
  pointer-events: none;
}

.fa-svg-icon a {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```